# uncompress and read gzip file in scala

Tags: scala, gzip, scalding

In Scala, how does one uncompress the text contained in `file.gz` so that it can be processed? I would be happy with either having the contents of the file stored in a variable, or saving it as a local file so that it can be read in by the program after.

Specifically, I am using Scalding to process compressed log data, but Scalding does not define a way to read them in `FileSource.scala`.

Comment: You can extract the content from gzip using Java `java.util.zip. GZipInputStream` and then work with its content

Comment: with the better-files library, it's `myFile.newInputStream.gzipped.lines`, according to https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's my version:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader
import java.io.InputStreamReader
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream
import java.io.FileInputStream

class BufferedReaderIterator(reader: BufferedReader) extends Iterator[String] {
  override def hasNext() = reader.ready
  override def next() = reader.readLine()
}

object GzFileIterator {
  def apply(file: java.io.File, encoding: String) = {
    new BufferedReaderIterator(
      new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
          new GZIPInputStream(
            new FileInputStream(file)), encoding)))
  }
}
```

Then do:

```
val iterator = GzFileIterator(new java.io.File("test.txt.gz"), "UTF-8")
iterator.foreach(println)
```

Comment: Just wanted to say I used this solution, but the BufferedReaderIterator in this solution produced null lines, due to the nature of reader.ready method.
Here is a  correct [implementation of an iterator on top of a BufferedReader](http://viewfromthefringe.blogspot.de/2007/10/making-bufferedreader-iterable.html)  that I found

Comment: Out of curiosity, what aspect of the file caused the null lines?

Comment: It is discussed in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244839/does-bufferedreader-ready-method-ensure-that-readline-method-does-not-return): "...The result of calling ready() tells you absolutely nothing about the content you'll get back from a read() call, and so cannot be used to elide a null check."
I am using the iterator to read .gz text files from S3 buckets and some lines from the iterator yielded null objects.  Then I changed to the implementation of the iterator that I attached and stopped experiencing this behavior.