# How can I download and add static files to a project using SBT

Tags: scala, testing, gzip, sbt, task

I want to add some files to test a library that I am writing.

The tests are available in a compressed file in a URI and I just want to download that file and uncompress its contents to a folder before testing.

I was reading the documentation on SBT and there is a Generate sources/resources task.

Also, it seems easy to uncompress a zip file in Scala ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17436549/uncompress-and-read-gzip-file-in-scala)).

So I think, I could glue those 2 pieces together, but I wonder if there is some simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this (syntax for Sbt 0.13.2), in your `build.sbt`:

```
resourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val location = url("http://path/to/your/zip-file.zip")
  IO.unzipURL(location, resourceManaged.value / "my-custom-files").toSeq
}.taskValue
```

Comment: Yes, it works. But the remark of using 0.13.2 syntax is important. I was using SBT 0.13.1 and it was giving me an error :)