# get empty notification in production server

Tags: java, google-glass, google-mirror-api

I develop a google glass app using mirror api. during development I used **"Introspected tunnels to localhost"** to receive the notification.

Now I uploaded my app on production server. So now I configure my callback URL as my domain name like **https://www.mydomain.com:8443/notify**. But I get empty notification.

in notify servlet:

```
BufferedReader notificationReader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
String notificationString = ""; 
int lines = 0;

while (notificationReader.ready()) {
    notificationString += notificationReader.readLine();
    lines++;

    if (lines > 1000) {
        throw new IOException(
                "Attempted to parse notification payload that was unexpectedly long.");
    }
}

LOG.info("\ngot raw notification : " + notificationString);
```

in catalina.out

```
Feb 13, 2014 12:51:48 PM com.google.glassware.NotifyServlet doPost
INFO: got raw notification :
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: It sounds like you have a gremlin in there that you need to isolate. What happens if you use curl to post something to the notification endpoint? Does the content you post make it to your log?

Comment: yea this is my log and it is empty. No i didn't use curl yet. which portion should I isolate?

Comment: Rudy - I think Jenny is suggesting that you use curl to mimic the notification you expect to get from your client side application. Does this make sense?

Comment: yea, i am trying to do.

Comment: what is your website notification address and an example call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                String line = "";
                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                                       new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {         
                    stringBuffer.append(line);
                }
                notificationString = stringBuffer.toString();
```

Hope it will works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `readLine()` method.One of the answer from [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244839/does-bufferedreader-ready-method-ensure-that-readline-method-does-not-return) suggest not using ready() for such requirements.

> The ready method tells us if the Stream is ready to be read.
>   Imagine your stream is reading data from a network socket. In this
>   case, the stream may not have ended, because the socket has not been
>   closed, yet it may not be ready for the next chunk of data, because
>   the other end of the socket has not pushed any more data.
>
> In the above scenario, we cannot read any more data until the remote
>   end pushes it, so we have to wait for the data to become available, or
>   for the socket to be closed. The ready() method tells us when the data
>   is available.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and I changed the code to look like this:

```
 StringBuffer jb = new StringBuffer();
 String notificationString = "";
 String line = "";
 BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
 while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {         
     jb.append(line);
 }
 notificationString = jb.toString();
```

Comment: U almost there. just need to change BufferedReader, like BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream())); then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
while(notificationReader.ready()) {
    notificationString = notificationString.concat(notificationReader.readLine());
    lines++;
}
```